# php curl to website without captcha

Tags: php, curl

Please bear with me as I am completely new to php curl and its intricacies. I've picked up some tips here but am still stuck (for days) so hope someone can really help!

When I curl to this url http://agentnet.propertyguru.com.sg/ex_login?w=1&redirect=/ex_home, there is a key difference between viewing it using my web browser vs curl. i.e. a captcha field (together with an error message) will appear when viewed via curl. There is no captcha or error message when viewed via browser. How do I do it such that curl produces the same result as a browser?

Here's my simple code snippet.

```
$loginUrl = 'http://agentnet.propertyguru.com.sg/ex_login?w=1&redirect=/ex_home';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
$cookie = realpath('cookie.txt');  // 'FSPrompt-6496=completed;' is stored in this file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);

$request_headers = array();
$request_headers[] = 'Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8';
$request_headers[] = 'Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.5';
$request_headers[] = 'Connection: Keep-Alive';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);
$msg = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: **I do see Captcha Code Box**

Comment: That's exactly the problem... Captcha does not appear when viewed using a web browser (I used IE9 and Firefox 30.0)

Comment: It does Appear in Chrome 35, Firefox 30 and IE 11

Comment: I have no idea why your browsers show the captcha. It's not going to be constructive if i carry on stating that my browsers do not display the captcha and you reiterate that yours does lol

Answer (score 1):

This site require cookie to let you login.

1. When you access /ex_login (without cookie), it redirect you to /distil_identify_cookie.html?uid=
2. At /distil_identify_cookie.html?uid=…, the browser have to save cookie value, it redirect you back to the first login page.
3. On the first login page, you have valid cookie, no more cookie init needed.

So you have to update your script to save the cookie correctly. [Guzzle](http://guzzlephp.org) is great library to build http client.

Comment: Can you advise how I save the cookies at  /distil_identify_cookie.html? I don't have a clue how to go about this...Sorry again for the trouble!

Comment: Darn, my php version is 5.3+ but Guzzle requires 5.4. Should have looked at the installation requirements first... is there another way to do this?

Comment: Guzzle 3.x does not require 5.4 (:

Comment: I just realised that I probably wasn't clear in my earlier comment. The reason why I have trouble saving the cookies is because the page gets redirected back to the first login page even when I set curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE); I could not access $_GET['uid'] as a result. Would really appreciate your further assistance. By the way, do you do freelance work Andy?